# docker buildx create --use mybuilder => Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: dns, docker

Creating a builder

```
$ docker buildx create --use mybuilder
romantic_galileo
```

Observing the  "Temporary Failure in Name resolution" error:

```
$ docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE           DRIVER/ENDPOINT      STATUS PLATFORMS
romantic_galileo *  docker-container            
  romantic_galileo0 tcp://mybuilder:2375 error during connect: Get "http://mybuilder:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup mybuilder: Temporary failure in name resolution
default             docker                       
  default           default              running linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

Cannot build:

```
$ docker buildx build -t “${DOCKER_USER}/buildx-test:latest” \
  --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le --push .
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                   
error: no valid drivers found: error during connect: Get "http://mybuilder:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup mybuilder: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This seems to be some sort of internal networking error but I have been unable to find good info on the cause which might suggest a resolution.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Docker 20.10.17

Standard install of Docker from their repo using their instructions:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Setup the system with instructions:
[Building Multi-Architecture Docker Images With Buildx by Artur Klauser, Jan 18, 2020](https://medium.com/@artur.klauser/building-multi-architecture-docker-images-with-buildx-27d80f7e2408)

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? I ran into the same error when docker-container driver is used with BuildX. Thanks!